# Bluetooth LE Device Discovery in UWP

Tags: c#, ios, windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

Do the Windows Bluetooth LE APIs support connecting to and discovering services offered by an iPhone? I tried running the "Bluetooth Low Energy C# Sample" and my iPhone does not display when I attempt to enumerate devices. Has anyone been able to successfully interact with an iPhone using the Bluetooth APIs on Windows? (Specifically, I am using Windows 10 version 1809 and an iPhone SE running iOS 12.1)

Comment: Could show more detail about the services offered by an iPhone? I tested with apple watch and I could discover the device in the watcher list with BLE code sample.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I was specifically trying to work with Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS). I don’t know why the iPhone isn’t showing up when I enumerate devices, I have the iPhone on the Bluetooth settings screen and paired with the PC. I found with a couple PCs running 1803 and 1809 that pairing works kind of oddly with my iPhone SE- pairing will succeed but whenever I try to connect from iOS to the PC the phone will say the PC is “not supported”. I’ve heard other people have run into this problem. Is there a known cause as to what makes enumeration work and what does not?

Comment: emm, your means your iOS project does not work with bluetooth, right?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It may be more of a problem with connecting iPhones to Windows in the first place. Where would I file this type of a bug?

Comment: Some examples of others with this problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8408097
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hello/iphone-6s-says-laptop-is-not-supported/83291c24-0315-49e5-8385-b2b0715a73d3
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/iphone-wont-connect-via-bluetooth/7affa5f4-51e7-42cc-91be-0c9adbd9a2db

Comment: Have you confirmed that your iPhone is indeed doing BLE Advertising?